# Markdig not converting Umlauts

Tags: html, markdown, diacritics

Did someone already manage to make Markdig convert Umlauts from Markdown to HTML? Do I need to create my own pipeline for that?

Comment: What is the encoding of your source document? When you include an umlaut in your source document and convert to HTML, what character sequence is in the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that Markdig converts the Umlauts properly but instead of a full HTML document it creates just HTML fragments which have to be embedded in a HTML document with proper encoding in the header.

(from: https://github.com/lunet-io/markdig/issues/86)